# Any downloadable asp.net apps which resemble 37signals apps?

Tags: asp.net

[37signals](http://www.37signals.com) has some popular online web apps. There are some free alternatives (mostly PHP) which are downloadable where one can install on one own server.

Are there any similar app for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet

Comment: I am looking for more complete polished apps. Not starter kits, hobby projects, half baked apps, directory sites where I have to wade through hundreds of apps, etc..  I need specific full blown apps.

Comment: I was looking for specific examples and not url's to asp.net app directories  but since no one added any I'll accept this.